# checkout/update/confirm error “something went wrong” Spree + heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, spree

I'm having an issue with spree when deployed to heroku. Everything works except when you press the place order button.

The weird thing is the order does go through, when I check the dashboard at the payment gateway it does go through and the same being when you refresh the page. But your not shown the order. It just wont show the order confirmation page. After looking at the log I did notice this:

I already configured Braintree and it works fine when running a local server, but in heroku it doesnt seem to work anymore.

Update: Heroku log

```
2015-09-28T21:00:14.617116+00:00 app[web.1]: [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [ee2aedeb-307e-4cef-a847-6929d31b1988] Performed ActionMailer::DeliveryJob from Inline(mailers) in 458.82ms
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621114+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621117+00:00 app[web.1]: Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25):
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621119+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:541:in `initialize'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621121+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:541:in `open'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621122+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:541:in `tcp_socket'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621124+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:551:in `block in do_start'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621125+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:89:in `block in timeout'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621126+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:99:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621128+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:99:in `timeout'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621132+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:550:in `do_start'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621133+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/smtp.rb:520:in `start'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621135+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mail-2.6.3/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:112:in `deliver!'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621136+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mail-2.6.3/lib/mail/message.rb:2141:in `do_delivery'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621138+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mail-2.6.3/lib/mail/message.rb:236:in `block in deliver'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621139+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.3/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:543:in `block in deliver_mail'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621141+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621143+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621144+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621145+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.3/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:541:in `deliver_mail'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621146+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/mail-2.6.3/lib/mail/message.rb:236:in `deliver'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621147+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.3/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:85:in `deliver_now'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621149+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.3/lib/action_mailer/delivery_job.rb:10:in `perform'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621150+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/execution.rb:32:in `block in perform_now'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621151+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:115:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621152+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:115:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621154+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:553:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621160+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621161+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621163+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:496:in `block (2 levels) in around'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621164+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:341:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621165+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:341:in `block (2 levels) in simple'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621167+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/logging.rb:23:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621168+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/logging.rb:23:in `block (4 levels) in <module:Logging>'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621169+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621171+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621172+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621173+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/logging.rb:22:in `block (3 levels) in <module:Logging>'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621174+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/logging.rb:43:in `block in tag_logger'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621176+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621177+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621178+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621180+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/logging.rb:43:in `tag_logger'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621181+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/logging.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Logging>'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621186+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:439:in `instance_exec'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621187+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:439:in `block in make_lambda'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621189+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:340:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621190+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:340:in `block in simple'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621191+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:495:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621192+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:495:in `block in around'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621194+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621195+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621196+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `run_callbacks'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621198+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/execution.rb:31:in `perform_now'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621199+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/execution.rb:21:in `execute'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621200+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/inline_adapter.rb:14:in `enqueue'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621202+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/enqueuing.rb:71:in `block in enqueue'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621203+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:115:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621204+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:115:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621205+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:553:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621206+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621208+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621209+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:496:in `block (2 levels) in around'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621210+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:341:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621211+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:341:in `block (2 levels) in simple'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621213+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/logging.rb:14:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621214+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/logging.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <module:Logging>'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621215+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/logging.rb:43:in `block in tag_logger'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621217+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621218+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621219+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621221+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/logging.rb:43:in `tag_logger'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621222+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/logging.rb:13:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Logging>'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621223+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:439:in `instance_exec'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621225+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:439:in `block in make_lambda'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621226+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:340:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621227+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:340:in `block in simple'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621228+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:495:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621229+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:495:in `block in around'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621230+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621232+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621233+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `run_callbacks'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621234+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/enqueuing.rb:67:in `enqueue'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621238+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activejob-4.2.3/lib/active_job/configured_job.rb:13:in `perform_later'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621240+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.3/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:112:in `enqueue_delivery'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621241+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionmailer-4.2.3/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:68:in `deliver_later'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621242+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/spree_core-3.0.0/app/models/spree/order.rb:340:in `deliver_order_confirmation_email'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621244+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/spree_core-3.0.0/app/models/spree/order.rb:328:in `finalize!'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621245+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/eval_helpers.rb:58:in `evaluate_method'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621246+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/callback.rb:192:in `block in run_methods'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621247+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/callback.rb:191:in `each'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621248+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/callback.rb:191:in `run_methods'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621249+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/callback.rb:159:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621251+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/transition.rb:394:in `block (2 levels) in after'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621252+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/transition.rb:394:in `each'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621253+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/transition.rb:394:in `block in after'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621254+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/transition.rb:392:in `catch'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621255+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/transition.rb:392:in `after'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621257+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/transition.rb:195:in `run_callbacks'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621258+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/transition_collection.rb:127:in `run_callbacks'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621260+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/transition_collection.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in perform'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621261+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/transition_collection.rb:63:in `catch'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621262+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/transition_collection.rb:63:in `block in perform'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621263+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/transition_collection.rb:186:in `within_transaction'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621264+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/transition_collection.rb:62:in `perform'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621265+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/transition.rb:163:in `perform'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621267+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/event.rb:155:in `fire'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621268+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/event.rb:219:in `block in add_actions'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621269+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/machine.rb:725:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621270+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/state_machines-0.4.0/lib/state_machines/machine.rb:725:in `block (2 levels) in define_helper'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621271+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/spree_frontend-3.0.0/app/controllers/spree/checkout_controller.rb:30:in `update'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621273+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621274+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621275+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621276+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621277+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:115:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621278+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:115:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621280+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:553:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621281+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621282+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:503:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621286+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `run_callbacks'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621287+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621288+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621289+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621291+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621292+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621293+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621294+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621296+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621297+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621298+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621299+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionview-4.2.3/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621301+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621302+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621303+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in action'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621305+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621306+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:76:in `dispatch'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621307+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:45:in `serve'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621308+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621309+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621311+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.617755+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3309ms (ActiveRecord: 449.9ms)
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621312+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621313+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621314+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621315+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621317+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:51:in `serve'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621318+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621319+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621320+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621321+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621322+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621324+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621325+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621326+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621328+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:38:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621329+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621330+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621336+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621338+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621339+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621383+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621385+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621386+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:653:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621387+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621389+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:84:in `run_callbacks'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621390+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621391+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621392+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621393+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621395+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621396+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621397+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621398+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621399+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621401+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621402+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621403+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621404+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621406+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.3/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621407+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621408+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621409+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621411+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621412+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621413+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.13.4/lib/puma/server.rb:541:in `handle_request'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621416+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.13.4/lib/puma/server.rb:388:in `process_client'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621417+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.13.4/lib/puma/server.rb:270:in `block in run'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621419+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.13.4/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:106:in `call'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621420+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.13.4/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:106:in `block in spawn_thread'
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621422+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-09-28T21:00:14.621423+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-09-28T21:00:14.629494+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/checkout/update/confirm" host=shuabe-car.herokuapp.com request_id=e44c7575-4835-48a7-bd1a-e5c2c4a6e737 fwd="104.230.226.189" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3330ms status=500 bytes=1669
```

Comment: please provide the upper part of traceback log.

Comment: do you want me to run `heroku logs --tail`?

Comment: ok, I was looking at the log and noticed `Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25):`, action mailler? I'll copy the log

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ I updated the log to include the error, I didn't setup my actionmailer, its still the spree@example.com

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ I went ahead and installed `gem 'spree_mail_settings', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_mail_settings', branch: '3-0-stable'` but in the settings I dont see the `mail method settings` option

Comment: It was Actionmailer, it wasn't setup. I created it and now it works. Thanks for the help